# CSS positioning of error messages exactly above the input text box inline

Tags: css, html, dom

Hi I am looking to design CSS for html pages and below is m problem. I have two text boxes side by side put in an inline container.

I am now validating the inputs and want to display the error message exactly above the respective text box. So, I have created spans and put them in an inline-container of lesser height and thought of displaying. But the problem is:

**Case-1**: 
The validation message for the second text box shifts left if the length of the error message is short. How do I avoid this?

**Case-2**: 
If the validation message for input text box 1 is long, it is making the error message of text box 2 to shift extreme right. In this case, I want the validation message of text box 1 to be in multiple lines above the area of text box 1

MY HTML:

```
<div class="inline-container1">
    <ul><li><span class="validationMessage"
                data-bind="validationMessage: firstName" /></li>
         <li><span class="validationMessage"
                data-bind="validationMessage: lastName" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="name" class="inline-container">         
    <ul>
        <li> <input id="firstName"
                name="firstName" type="text" class="required-input"
                placeholder="First Name *" data-bind="value: firstName" /> 
        </li>
        <li> <input id="lastName"
                name="lastName" type="text" class="required-input"
                placeholder="Last Name *" data-bind="value: lastName" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

MY CSS:

```
.inline-container1 ul li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    min-height: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 230px;
}

.inline-container1 {     
}

.inline-container1 ul
{
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

     .validationMessage {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #F00; 
    display: inline;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your javascript is probably handling the error validation so you should look for that class and position it to be above the field.  If I could see this in action I could help you.

Comment: Hi Chad, my java script is hadnling true... but it is only giving the error message, but we are doing it using css about where we are displaying the error message .... How please let me know how we can do this in any other ways

Comment: Post a url and I can show you what to do.

Comment: @pret Chad had asked you to post sample code - this can be done using a tool like jsfiddle (see the answer from mrmoje below.  This is what Chad requested to improve your question to help him give you an answer.

Comment: @pret Please post the JavaScript code that interacts with your HTML and CSS.

Comment: @pret I have created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3oqtcsnd/ - you could improve  your post by adding the necessary JavaScript to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Fiddle i created to help -> http://jsfiddle.net/Moje/dTvKM/
Fullscreen -> http://jsfiddle.net/Moje/dTvKM/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<div class="ctnr">
    <span class="vMsg" data-bind="validationMessage: firstName">Val. msg for txtbox 1</span>
    <span class="vMsg" data-bind="validationMessage: lastName" >Val. msg for txtbox 2</span>
</div>
<div class="ctnr">         
    <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" class="required-input" placeholder="First Name *" 
    data-bind="value: firstName" />
    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" class="required-input" placeholder="Last Name *" 
    data-bind="value: lastName" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{font-family:sans;}
.ctnr > *{ display: inline-block; width: 40%;}
.vMsg{
    display:relative;
    top:-40px;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:red;
    padding:2px;
}
input[type=text]{-webkit-appearance:none;outline:none;border:none;}
#firstName{border:3px solid black;}
#lastName{border:3px solid red;}
```

You can tweak it further to suit your needs.